# Http GET and POST method in ios

Tags: ios, http, post, request

i need to post my value to the test WebView i try'd but my value didnt post and no change while iam running

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"643c30f73a"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"XXXXX.com"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: i dono how to post my values to website can any one give simple steps to catch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its worked for me,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://your_url.com"];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"arg1=%@&arg2=%@", @"val1",@"val2"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[webView loadRequest: request];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing the required delegate methods for NSURLConnection?

See the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html for details and example implementations.

Implementing the delegate methods will at least give you an indication of any error that is occurring.